# How can I convert an Int to a CString?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I can convert a `Double` to a `CString` using `_ecvt`

```
result_str=_ecvt(int,15,&decimal,&sign);
```

So, is there a method like the one above that converts an `int` to `CString`?

Comment: Note: The `cstring` tag is for the standard C++ header `cstring`, not for Microsofts string thing.

Comment: Maybe `itoa` is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
CString str;
str.Format("%d", 5);
```

In your case, try `_T("%d")` or `L"%d"` rather than `"%d"`

Comment: Can't do it much faster than that. You may want to wrap the string with the `_T` macro to match the `LPCTSTR` parameter type.

Comment: @Eslam How specifically did it not work? Didn't compile? Runtime error? Wrong result?

Comment: @Daniel, the following error arises error C2664: 'void ATL::CStringT<BaseType,StringTraits>::Format(const wchar_t *,...)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [3]' to 'const wchar_t *'

Comment: @Eslam Try `_T("%d")` or `L"%d"` rather than `"%d"`.

Comment: It is not working for me! I am getting error 'cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [3]' to 'const unsigned short *'. Weird.

Answer (score 8):

If you want something more similar to your example try _itot_s. On Microsoft compilers _itot_s points to _itoa_s or _itow_s depending on your Unicode setting:

```
CString str;
_itot_s( 15, str.GetBufferSetLength( 40 ), 40, 10 );
str.ReleaseBuffer();
```

it should be slightly faster since it doesn't need to parse an input format.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename Type>
CString ToCString (Type value)
    {
    return std::to_wstring (value).data ();
    }

int main ()
    {
    const auto msg = ToCString (10);
    std::wcout << msg.GetString () << std::endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CString(std::to_string(123).c_str())
```